# programmatically show tooltip using jqueryui

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I need to display a tooltip after some event(on another element)

How can I display a tooltip on a specified element in case of an event (like with mouseover) with jquery ui 1.9m6 ? You can guess what I need looking at the sample code below:

```
function myFunction(sender){
     if (sender.value!=""){
      var val1=parseInt(sender.value);
      if (val1>10000)
        //In this case I need to show a tooltip on the sender element with the content:"Amount exceeds the limit"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple html and jQuery tooltip you can look at this : http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/tooltip/default.html

For more graphical and rich tooltip you can try to use qTip; is a specific jQuery template, not jQuery UI, but very powerful and simple:
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/
new rel. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download

Comment: thanks . see again in demos and doc and find it : 
$(selector).tooltip('open') and $(selector).tooltip('close')

Answer (score -1):

You can check out qTip2. It is pretty powerful and should do what you need it to.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download

Comment: i am now using jquery ui 1.9m6 and think that it have what i need. but don't know how use it. so question - how in jquery ui programmaticaly fire same action for tooltip